# Either of 2 columns is always redundant -- is there a better solution?

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design

Say, I want to create a form for a feedback. If a registered user submits a feedback, his email address is used automatically because he's authenticated. If an anonymous user does that, he has to enter his email manually. My table would look like this:

```
feedbacks(id, user_id, email, body)
```

As you can see, it has a redundant column: either user_id or email. And for those who's not familiar with the database structure it'll be confusing: why both email and user_id? can they both be null? or both have a value at the same time? in reality, only one of them must have a value, which isn't possibly to achieve on database level using constraints. Also, what if I by mistake insert values in both columns?

Thus, I wonder, is there any way to **change its structure** so that it's more wise and that issue described above has become resolved? Using a trigger isn't what I'm looking for.

In other words, the issue is "either of 2 columns is always redundant".

Comment: you probably meant "not registered" - not "anonymous"?..

Comment: You should store the email in both cases. The user may change their email address at a later time.

Comment: @Serge, or maybe not if it's not allowed. or if there's history of changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you had **several** mutually exclusive columns, then you might have a good case for something called **entity sub-typing**.  As it is, there is no good design reason for adding all of the extra overhead of this design pattern.

These are the basic options that you have:

1. **Two mutually exclusive columns in one table** - This is your current design.  This is a good design because it lets you define a proper *foreign key constraint* on your `user_id`.  You mention that it may be confusing for people that don't know the database well because the same kind of information might appear in one or the other place in the table.  However, it's important to remember that even though both columns contain a string that happens to be in the form of an email address, to your system these things are *semantically distinct*.  One is a foreign key to your user table.  The other is a means of contacting (or identifying?) a non-member.  You could avoid this apparent confusion in one of two ways: (a) give a more descriptive name to your `email` column, such as `non_member_email` or (b) create a view that coalesces `user_id` and `email` into a single column for displaying this information to people who would otherwise be confused.
2. **Entity Subtyping** - This approach has you create separate tables for logically separate groups of predicates (columns).  These are joined together by a *supertype table* which gives a common primary key for all logical subtypes, as well as holding all other common predicates.  You can google around to learn more about this design pattern.  As I've already mentioned, this is overkill for your case because you only have one pair of mutually exclusive columns.  If you think it's confusing to have this then having three tables (supertype, member subtype, non-member subtype) will really be confusing.
3. **Column Overloading** - This approach would have you combine both columns into a single one.  This is *feasible* because you only need room in your table for one email address at a time.  This is **a terrible idea** because it prevents you from creating a declarative referential constraint on `user_id` which is a very important tool for maintaining your data's referential integrity.  It also conflates two semantically different pieces of information, which violates good database design principles.

**The best choice is number 1.**  Don't worry about having two mutually exclusive columns or if you think you can't "comment" your way around the confusion you think this might cause with more descriptive column names, then use a view to hide the "complexity" of storing two things that look similar in two separate columns.

Answer (score 1):

If one must be exclusively filled:

```
create table feedbacks (
    id integer,
    user_id text,
    email text,
    body text,
    check ((user_id is null)::int + (email is null)::int = 1)
);
```

The cast from boolean to integer yields either 1 or 0, so the sum must be 1.

Comment: nope, the issue is "Either of 2 columns is always redundant"

Comment: @Kevin I don't get it.

Comment: If both are present, the sum will be two and the new row will be rejected.  If neither are present, the sum will be zero and the new row will be rejected.  Why doesn't this solve the problem?

Comment: I mean, you've proposed the solution for a wrong problem. I asked about a different thing.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the email field. If the user is registered, enter their user_id as you do now. If the user is not registered, search the user table for an anonymous entry with that email address. If exists, use that user_id. Otherwise, create an entry in the user table named 'Anonymous', storing the address and use the newly created user_id. There are two advantages:

1. You don't need mutually exclusive fields. As you have already noticed, these can be the cause of a lot of confusion and extra work to keep the data clean.
2. If an anonymous poster later registers, the existing "anonymous" user entry can be updated, thus preserving the user_id value and preserving all feedback (and any other activity you track for anonymous users) entered before registering. That is, if a user anonymously enters a few feedbacks then registers, the previous feedbacks remain associated with the now named user.

Answer (score 0):

I might misunderstand the question, but why you say it is impossible to do with constraints?..

```
t=# CREATE TABLE feedbacks (
t(#     id integer,
t(#     user_id text CHECK (case when email is null then user_id is distinct from null else user_id is null end),
t(#     email text CHECK (case when user_id is null then email is distinct from null else email is null end),
t(#     body text
t(# );
CREATE TABLE
t=# insert into feedbacks select 1,null,null,'t';
ERROR:  new row for relation "feedbacks" violates check constraint "feedbacks_check1"
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (1, null, null, t).
t=# insert into feedbacks select 1,'t','t','t';
ERROR:  new row for relation "feedbacks" violates check constraint "feedbacks_check1"
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (1, t, t, t).
t=# insert into feedbacks select 1,'t',null,'t';
INSERT 0 1
t=# insert into feedbacks select 1,null,'t','t';
INSERT 0 1
t=# select * from feedbacks ;
 id | user_id | email | body
----+---------+-------+------
  1 | t       |       | t
  1 |         | t     | t
(2 rows)
```

Comment: alright, insert either of them is possible, but still the schema itself -- isn't ok because either of the columns is always redundant.